# Swagger-php how to exclude entire /vendor folder but append one subfolder with shared models

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, swagger-php

The package I'm using is [Swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php)

I currently generate swagger file by executing:

> ./vendor/bin/openapi --output storage/app/swagger/swagger.json
>   --exclude tests --exclude storage --exclude vendor ./

And I have some models that I share between multiple api`s so I want swagger schema definition to live with those models at

> ./vendor/utilities/php-general-tools/src/models/

So I need to include that folder but its currently excluded.. the error shown is

```
$ref "#/components/schemas/" not found for @OA\JsonContent() in ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.. so apparently you can add multiple paths as last argument separated by space like

```
./vendor/bin/openapi --output storage/app/swagger/swagger.json --exclude vendor --exclude tests --exclude storage ./ ./vendor/utilities/php-general-tools/src/models/
```

so both `./` and `./vendor/utilities/php-general-tools/src/models/` will be scanned for annotations